# Celery==5.1.2 AttributeError: 'DynamicField' object has no attribute 'null'

Tags: celery, celery-task

Recently we have migrated from py2 (celery==3.1.19) to py3(Celery==5.1.2). We started getting Unrecoverable error: AttributeError("'DynamicField' object has no attribute 'null'") error on few records when passed by apply_async. We are not getting this issue when same set of records are processed on (celery==3.1.19) but it is there on (Celery==5.1.2)

Detailed Stack Trace:

```
[2023-04-04 08:51:01,834: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: AttributeError("'DynamicField' object has no attribute 'null'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 326, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 618, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 81, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 362, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 120, in on_readable
    return self._on_event(fd, _pycurl.CSELECT_IN)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 137, in _on_event
    self._process_pending_requests()
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 143, in _process_pending_requests
    self._process(curl)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 189, in _process
    request.on_ready(self.Response(
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 167, in __call__
    svpending(*ca, **ck)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 160, in __call__
    return self.throw()
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 157, in __call__
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 98, in _transback
    return callback(ret)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 160, in __call__
    return self.throw()
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 157, in __call__
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 98, in _transback
    return callback(ret)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 160, in __call__
    return self.throw()
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 157, in __call__
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 96, in _transback
    callback.throw()
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 94, in _transback
    ret = filter_(*args + (ret,), **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 577, in _on_messages_ready
    callbacks[qname](msg_parsed)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 622, in _callback
    return callback(message)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 626, in _receive_callback
    return on_m(message) if on_m else self.receive(decoded, message)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 586, in on_task_received
    strategy(
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/strategy.py", line 201, in task_message_handler
    handle(req)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 221, in _process_task_sem
    return self._quick_acquire(self._process_task, req)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/semaphore.py", line 57, in acquire
    callback(*partial_args, **partial_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 226, in _process_task
    req.execute_using_pool(self.pool)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/request.py", line 695, in execute_using_pool
    result = apply_async(
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/concurrency/base.py", line 152, in apply_async
    return self.on_apply(target, args, kwargs,
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1530, in apply_async
    self._quick_put((TASK, (result._job, None, func, args, kwds)))
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py", line 859, in send_job
    body = dumps(tup, protocol=protocol)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 214, in __getstate__
    data["_data"] = self.to_mongo()
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 267, in to_mongo
    data = super().to_mongo(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/moe-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 368, in to_mongo
    if (value is not None) or (field.null):
AttributeError: 'DynamicField' object has no attribute 'null'
[2023-04-04 08:51:02,948: WARNING/MainProcess] Restoring 1 unacknowledged message(s)
[2023-04-04 08:51:02,948: WARNING/MainProcess]
```

This error is coming from the installed package, hence we are not able to identify the record causing this issue.